# Get all html tags with Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Does anybody knows how can I get all the HTML tags that exist in a page?
I need to get only the tags without their IDs or other attributes, and create a kind of tree-structure of them.
Prefer to do that with Javascript or JQuery.

**For example, This HTML code:**

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>
      Example Page 
  </title>
  </head>
  < body>
    <h1 style="somestyle">
      Blabla
  </h1>
  <div id="id">
    <table id="formid">
      <tr>
        <td>
        </td>
      </tr>
      </table>
  </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

**should return return:**

*html

head

title

body

h1

div

table

tr

td*

Comment: `document.querySelectorAll('*')`. or traverse the DOM (document.body) recursively with `.children`.

Comment: What is the use case for this? It is not trivial reproducing the DOM

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/TreeWalker

Comment: To clarify, do you want the output you described under "will return:", or an indented tree-like version of that?

Comment: It doesn't matter so much.. @NicolasMcCurdy, I tried to do this with querySelectorAll but it return a lot of junk with it and I need the tag name only.

Answer (score 11):

You can pass a `*` to [`getElementsByTagName()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.getElementsByTagName) so that it will return all elements in a page:

```
var all = document.getElementsByTagName("*");

for (var i=0, max=all.length; i < max; i++) {
     // Do something with the element here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Its a very simple piece of Javascript

```
document.querySelectorAll('*')
```

Try it out in the console log and it will show you all the tags in the document.

Another example is to `getElementsByTagName`

These do print out into an array, so you can then loop through the elements and doing different things on different elements.

Example:

```
var items = document.getElementsByTagName("*");
for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
    //do stuff
}
```

Comment: And, just to add a little more info, each HTML element will have a "tagName" property that gives the basic name you're looking for. It's uppercase by default

Answer (score 0):

I did it with `getElementsByTagName` and `.tagName` for every value in the return array.